# How to lint Android system / platform app

Tags: android, android-source, lint

It's easy to lint a third-party app by using Android Studio.
But I don't know how to lint a system app.
May be command line tool works, but I can not find the class file android and assign the class path.

Comment: You can just import the system app as an android project and run lint on that

Answer (score 1):

After days trying, I find the right way.

AOSP has a build-in lint tool in `prebuilts/devtools/tools/lint`,
after a "full make" you can lint your system app by using command `lint vendor/letv/apps/Camera/`.

However, since Android M "[Jack](https://source.android.com/source/jack)" is default compiler and there is no classed.jar in `out/target/common/obj/APPS/StvCamera_intermediates`,
So you'll get a Error like `No bytecode found: Has the project been built?` when you line.

As a workaround, just use [dex2jar](https://github.com/pxb1988/dex2jar/releases) convert classes.dex to classes.jar

Further more, lint will get a wrong ModuleName if you set module name in Android.mk, and a modified version can found here https://github.com/likaci/android-lint-mod